# getting StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'FORBIDDEN', when accesing get api through below code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, erpnext

Below is the code sample

```
public string getIssueList(string email)
{
    dynamic JsonContent = "";
    string url = baseAddress + "resource/Issue/?fields=[%22subject%22,%22status%22]&filters=[[%22Issue%22,%22raised_by%22,%22=%22,%22" + email + "%22]]";

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
               | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
               | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
               | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("token", AccessToken);

    var APIResponse = client.GetAsync(url).Result;

    if (APIResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        JsonContent = APIResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        WriteToFile(" getIssueList APIResponse : " + JsonContent.ToString());
    }


    return JsonContent;
}
```

the link in above code is making some problem I think when I am sending get request in response it is getting StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'FORBIDDEN', Version: 1.1.....

I think it is not accepting the %22 => " in raw string " is also it is not working

Comment: It is more likely your token isn't correct because that is what the 403 normally means. Try without any fields or just `?fields=` and see if you still get a 403. Are you sure `new AuthenticationHeaderValue("token", AccessToken);` is corent? Is AccessToken a JWT? If yes, shouldn't `"token"` then be `"Bearer"` instead?

Comment: I tried without any parameter then it's working fine but when adding parameters it's not getting 200 ok response and data from server. I want to pass " in url, it's containing JSON data in url.

Comment: So you can't add the `"`? Did you try escaping the " with a \ like `"resource/Issue/?fields=[\"subject\"` ... etc ....

Comment: Yes I tried, but not working getting same response.and also resource/Issue/?fields= is getting replaced with resource/Issue?fields= automatically, is there any to way stop this replacement.

Comment: If you replace your string url line with just `string url = baseAddress + "resource/Issue/?fields=[\"subject\"]";`  does that work?

Comment: Not working same response, can we pass double quotes " in url, i think because of double quotes" it's showing that error

Comment: In my quick testing the URL seems to be encoded correctly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSHkI.png and the approach is inline with what ERPNext seems to expect https://frappeframework.com/docs/v13/user/en/guides/integration/rest_api/listing_documents so I'm out of ideas right now.

Comment: Ok boss, 'Met dank' Thanks for help

Comment: There are a number of side issues with the above code: setting `SecurityProtocol` is a bad idea, let .NET work out for itself what is the best protocol. `handler` `client` and `APIResponse` need disposing with `using`, although it's generally recommended to cache a single `client` with its `handler` for the lifetime of the app. Don't call `.Result` it could cause a deadlock, instead do `async` all the way.

Comment: hii,can you suggest me code for it, beacause i tried with 'using' also but still not getting expected result.